# UILabel text not changing?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

Unable to change text in lMenu_time (this is a UILabel) after it was initially set.
The call back is executed, I tested this, but the text won't change.
??  I am passing around the pointer and making adjustments to the UILabel. ??

lMenu_time and numerous others are defined in the header file. (not seen here)

```
UILabel *lMenu_time;
```

...

```
-(void) NewNumber:  (UIButton*) btn {       
    if (btn.tag == 102){
        iTime++;
        [lbl setText:@"time"];
        if(iTime > 20){iTime=1;}
        [lMenu_time setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:  @"Hold: %d", iTime]];
    }
    ....
}


- (void) menuItem: (UIView*)vMenu  menuButton:(UIButton*)bMenu menuLabel: (UILabel*)lMenu  menuPosX: (double)posX   menuLenX: (double)lenX  menuTagNum: (int)tagNum menuText: (NSString*)txtMenu{        
    bMenu = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [bMenu setFrame:CGRectMake(posX,0,lenX,25)];
    [bMenu setTag: tagNum];
    [bMenu addTarget:self action:@selector(NewNumber:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [vMenu addSubview:bMenu];


    lMenu = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(posX,0,lenX,25)] retain];
    [lMenu setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
    [lMenu setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:  txtMenu]];
    [lMenu setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14 ]];
    [lMenu setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
    [vMenu addSubview: lMenu];
}

- (void) menuBuild{
    pSelf = self;
    theString = @"";


    UIView *vMenu = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,25)];
    [pSelf.view addSubview:vMenu];
    [vMenu setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]]; 


    iTime = 2;
    [self menuItem:vMenu menuButton:bMenu_time menuLabel:lMenu_time menuPosX:240+20 menuLenX:60 menuTagNum:102  menuText:[NSString stringWithFormat:  @"Hold: %d", iTime]];

    ...    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just before you try to set the next, try adding

```
NSLog(@"My label is %@",lMenu_time);
```

Then, if your console outputs "My label is (nil)" you'll know that the problem is that the pointer to `lMenu_time` isn't being passed around properly.

Comment: I realize it is nil.  Not sure why it is null.  Not sure why it is... Even though I did UILabel "alloc", do I need to do a "retain" ?

Comment: Is lMenu_time a `@property` of your view controller?

Comment: Your code doesn't show whether or not `lMenu_time` is a global initialized in your header, or not.  It helps when you post complete code.  I can see where you're *initializing* the variable, but not where it is *declared*...

Comment: I added the snippet from the header file.  It is an instance variable

Comment: What is `menuBuild`? When is it called in relation to `NewNumber:`? Why are you passing lMenu if it is already an ivar?  Why not just initialize `lMenu_time = [[[UILabel alloc]...` directly?

Comment: Since I am using the same large section of code many many times, I broke it up 1 line for every 10.

Comment: menuBuild is called when the app is loaded

Answer (score 0):

Did you bind the label object to the controller in Interface builder?  If not I would bet this is an retention issue.  You do not post the code that builds the UILabel object, so if that is not done in IB, ensure you call retain or it will certainly be out of scope when you try and modify it.

Comment: the method called "menuItem" shows the code fore the UILabel object

Comment: That may be the issue then.  Are you ever initializing the control?  Nowhere in that method is "lMenu_time" referenced or touched.  I see "lMenu" there, but not "lMenu_time".

Comment: Yes it is initialized.  And I see the initialization text in the UILabel.  Just not the update on the callBack.

Comment: You never assign (alloc) anything to "lMenu_time", just lMenu.  Without more code to see I would start by looking there.

Comment: But I passed lMenu_time to the function where it is lMenu.  This is the question... why is the pointer not keeping its values?

Comment: Perhaps because you are passing in a reference to a control and subsequently giving it a new reference via Alloc which is then getting lost.  If the lMenu_time is a class-level property there should be no need to be passing it around.